# Auto-correlation vs Auto-covariance

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, covariance, cross-correlation

Autocorrelation is the cross-correlation of a signal with itself, and autocovariance is the cross-covariance of a signal with itself.

According to https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/correlation-and-covariance.html
the cross-correlation two wide-sense stationary random process, $x(n)$ and $y(n)$ is :

$R_{xy}(m) = E\{x(n+m)y(n) \}$

whereas the cross-covariance is defined as:

$C_{xy}(m) = E\{(x(n+m)-\mu_x)  (y(n)-\mu_y) \} = R_{xy}(m) - \mu_x\mu_y$

However, statsmodels https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html calls in its function for the autocorrelation (acf) the autocovariance function (acovf):

`avf = acovf(x, unbiased=unbiased, demean=True, fft=fft, missing=missing)`

where ***acovf*** subtracts the mean since ***demean*** is set to ***True***.

`xo = x - x.mean()`

But according to the definition, the cross-correlation is simply the dot product without subtracting the mean.
What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting everything correct. There is unfortunately inconsistency over the terms auto-correlation and cross-correlation in time-series and signal processing literatures. The mathworks link you shared is a signal processing toolbox, and defines auto and cross correlations without demeaning and normalizing, just as in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) page. The Normalization section of the wikipedia page notes down this difference. In time-series courses/lectures you'll see the normalized version of auto-covariance as your auto-correlation function, which is the definition `statsmodels` uses.

Comment: Looks like the signal processing literature is abusing/redefining statistical terms. (I do not think it is the other way around, at least by historical precedence.)